# Taking a column from a csv file and putting it into a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, import

I need to write some code in python that takes a column from an csv file and makes it a list. Here is my code until now.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
columns = defaultdict(list)
with open('Team1_BoMInput.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for (k,v) in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)

y = (columns['Quantity'])
x = (columns[('Actual Price')])

b = ['2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '3', '4', '1', '1', '1', '8', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '4', '1', '2', '2', '2', '1', '2', '2', '2', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1']
a = ['$6.41', '$14.97', '$6.78', '$11.44', '$22.61', '$1.58', '$11.68', '$19.99', '$12.99', '$3.66', '$24.99', '$1.04', '$0.09', '$1.92', '$4.80', '$1.50', '$17.92', '$1.36', '$65.52', '$24.38', '$1.91', '$3.40', '$13.79', '$39.55', '$1.94', '$3.38', '$11.34', '$18.33', '$21.13', '$8.24', '$30.14', '$125.97', '$26.54', '$8.58', '$12.77', '$11.42', '$1.32', '$2.63', '$8.58', '$0.40', '$0.57', '$2.54', '$2.83', '$1.41', '$9.03', '$3.38', '$5.98', '$4.51', '$2.54', '$6.76', '$4.51', '$1.13', '$14.24']

for i in range(0, len(b)):
    b[i] = float(b[i])
print(b)
x = ([s.strip('$') for s in a])
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x[i] = float(x[i])
print(x)
```

instead of having the values of a and b listed in the program, I want it to take the column from the csv file and use the values of that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @Irfan S, welcome to StackOverflow! It might be helpful if you could provide the issue you're having along with what has already been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Team1_BoMInput.csv")

y=list(df['Quantity'])
x=list(df['Actual Price'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Below Code, leveraging the `pandas` library for faster computations and lesser code

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Team1_BoMInput.csv")
quantity_list_value=list(df.loc[:,"Quantity"].astype(float).values)
price_list_value=list(df.loc[:,"Actual Price"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("$","")).astype(float).values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you code will not run unless you change it to this:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
columns = defaultdict(list)
with open('Team1_BoMInput.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for (k,v) in row.items():
            if k not in columns:
                columns[k] = list()
            columns[k].append(v)
    # Rest of your code
```

Comment: In pycharm, the code seems to run fine as of right now, but thank you.

Comment: I forgot to add a part to the question, I added it now.